Install R-3.6.3 on fedora linux 37 from source code
Im having some trouble installing the old R version R-3.6.3 on fedora linux 37(workstation edition), in the cran website the fedora section, r can be installed via the command
    $ sudo dnf install R

but u can't specify which version.
So i turned to installing it from the source code(on the same page). Once downloaded, I followed the instruction on the fedora website page for installing such type of software, the instruction are:
    $ tar -zxf R-3.6.3.tar.gz
    $ cd R-3.6.3/
    $ ./configure
    $ make
    $ sudo make install

the ./configure cmd gave me this output:
    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    loading site script './config.site'
    loading build-specific script './config.site'
    checking for pwd... /usr/bin/pwd
    checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
    checking for which... /usr/bin/which
    checking for less... /usr/bin/less
    checking for gtar... /usr/bin/gtar
    checking for tex... /usr/bin/tex
    checking for pdftex... /usr/bin/pdftex
    checking for pdflatex... /usr/bin/pdflatex
    checking for makeindex... /usr/bin/makeindex
    checking for texi2any... /usr/bin/texi2any
    checking whether texi2any version is at least 5.1... yes
    checking for ginstall-info... no
    checking for install-info... no
    checking for texi2dvi... /usr/bin/texi2dvi
    checking for kpsewhich... /usr/bin/kpsewhich
    checking for latex inconsolata package... found zi4.sty
    checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
    checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
    checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
    checking for bzip2... /usr/bin/bzip2
    checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
    using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
    checking for acroread... no
    checking for acroread4... no
    checking for xdg-open... /usr/bin/xdg-open
    checking for working aclocal... found
    checking for working autoconf... found
    checking for working autoheader... found
    checking for bison... no
    checking for byacc... no
    checking for yacc... no
    checking for notangle... false
    checking for realpath... /usr/bin/realpath
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking minix/config.h usability... no
    checking minix/config.h presence... no
    checking for minix/config.h... no
    checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    looking for a modern Fortran compiler
    checking for gfortran... gfortran
    checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
    checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking whether g++ -g -O2 can compile C++ code... yes
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -fvisibility... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -fvisibility... yes
    checking whether gfortran accepts -fvisibility... yes
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
    checking whether g++ can compile ObjC++... no
    checking whether  can compile ObjC++... no
    checking for Objective C++ compiler... no working ObjC++ compiler found
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /usr/bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for archiver @FILE support... @
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
    checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
    checking for mt... no
    checking if : is a manifest tool... no
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
    checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
    checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fPIC
    checking if gfortran PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
    checking if gfortran static flag -static works... no
    checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking for cos in -lm... yes
    checking for sin in -lm... yes
    checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
    checking readline/history.h usability... no
    checking readline/history.h presence... no
    checking for readline/history.h... no
    checking readline/readline.h usability... no
    checking readline/readline.h presence... no
    checking for readline/readline.h... no
    checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
    checking for main in -lncurses... no
    checking for main in -ltermcap... no
    checking for main in -ltermlib... no
    checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
    configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available

And the make cmd stopped and gave me this output:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Seems like the ./configure cmd did not do its job, how can I solve this problem?
I tried installing some libraries that are getting in the way of the ./configure cmd, but the problem persists

You asked (by default) for readline support, but you don't have the required library to support it.  Try ./configure --with-readline=no.  Don't bother trying make until you have a successful configure step.

You don't say why you want R 3.6.3, but I'd guess it's to support some package that won't run in current R.  Such packages are no longer supported by their authors, and more recent versions of R have identified problems in them that nobody has fixed, so I think you'd be better off finding a different way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Yes exactly, i need to work with a package at this version of R. I found that running sudo yum install readline-devel worked, but the overral cmd got interrupted by another thing that needs to be installed configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available this cmd fixed it sudo dnf install libX11-devel libXt-devel, but another thing checking whether PCRE support suffices... configure: error: pcre >= 8.20 library and headers are required this cmd fixed it sudo yum install pcre pcre-devel. And then it went through

It's good that it's working, but I'd wonder why that package doesn't work in current R -- there are likely issues with it that existed back in 3.6.3 as well, but weren't caught in the tests.

I try to post a new question about it, with more details and version

An easier way to run an older R version compared to building from source would be to get the respective versioned docker image from the rocker project
